# R error: installation of package had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, package

I've set up a daily R script to update all packages automatically:

```
## ---- Automatically update all packages and their dependencies -------
    options(install.packages.compile.from.source = "always")
    options(repos = c(CRAN = "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
    update.packages(ask = FALSE, dependencies = TRUE)
```

However I'm getting the following warnings when the script ends:

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  installation of package ‘agricolae’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  installation of package ‘brms’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  installation of package ‘gstat’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is there anything I can add/adapt in the code to fix those warnings?
My sessioninfo() is:
    R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 14393)

```
Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.2 tools_3.6.2
```

Comment: I think you should find out why they fail. Often it may be due to one dependency or sometimes conflicts between a new version and an existing one.It might be harder to do this in a daily script. Perhaps update packages weekly or monthly? I don't know why it's advantageous to update daily. What is  your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: You need to post the entire error message. The message `had non-zero exit status` simply means that *something* failed. But there must be more further up in the console.

Comment: @NelsonGon I've edited the post to include `sessionInfo()`. I think the issue will still occur even if I update on weekly/monthly basis.